# Passing an "indirect" object between pages in XMAL/C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have defined a Player object as follows:

```
public class Player
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string PlayerName { get; set; }
        public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
        public int TotalMatchesWon { get; set; }
        public int TotalMatchesLost { get; set; }
        public float WinPercentage { get; set; }
        public int Rank { get; set; }
    }
```

I store the Players in an SQLite database. I am implementing the following pages for an android app in Xamarin:

Roster -> Roster Detail -> Edit Player

The pages have the following functionality:

**Roster:** 
1. Roster.xmal contains a ListView of Players (the Roster), populated from the following function in Roster.xmal.cs.

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            listView.ItemsSource = await App.Database.GetPlayersAsync();
        }
```

2. Add a new player to the Roster. This calls the Edit Player page with empty fields using the following code in the  Roster.xmal.cs file.

```
async void OnPlayerAddedClicked(object send, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new RosterEntryPage
            {
                BindingContext = new Player()
            });
        }
```

3. You can select a Player from the list. This takes the SelectedItem and sends the Player to the PlayerDetailPage (also in the Roster.xmal.cs)

```
async void OnListViewItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new PlayerDetailPage
                {
                    BindingContext = e.SelectedItem as Player
                });
            }
        }
```

**Roster Detail:**
1. Displays the Player object that was passed to it from the OnListViewItemSelected() function. There's no code on the page that specifies that it has a Player, but I can reference the Player fields in the RosterDetails.xmal file (which is why I call it an "indirect" object) like this:

```
<Label Grid.Column="2" 
                               Text="{Binding PlayerName}"
                               FontSize="18"
                               FontAttributes="Bold" />
```

2. The user can click on a button to edit the player. This calls the RosterEntryPage again (like to add a new Player) but this time it passes the Player that it already has. This is the part that's broken. If I call the edit page directly from Roster.xmal, I can pre-populate all of the blank fields (but that's only the PlayerName) and update the SQLite record. I would like to pass the indirect object being used by RosterDetail.xmal to the edit page to do the same.

Here is the RosterDetail.xmal.cs:

```
public partial class PlayerDetailPage : ContentPage
    {
        public PlayerDetailPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        async void OnEditPlayerButtonClicked(object send, EventArgs e)
        {
            await floatingButtonEdit.ScaleTo(1.5, 500);
            await floatingButtonEdit.ScaleTo(0, 500, Easing.SpringOut);

            await Navigation.PushAsync(new RosterEntryPage
            {
                BindingContext = new Player()
            });
        }

    }
```

I know that the problem is the BindingContext = new Player(), but I have no idea what the replace it with. I've tried various things, such as BindingContext = e.Player but that gives an error that e.Player isn't valid. I've also tried changing the function parameters to match OnListViewItemSelected() so that it's OnEditPlayerButtonClicked(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) but that causes the app to crash.

**EDIT**
Here is the xmal for the page where you do data entry to either add a new player or edit an existing one.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Foosball.RosterEntryPage"
             Title="Roster Entry">
    <StackLayout Margin="20">

        <Editor Placeholder="Enter player name"
                Text="{Binding PlayerName}"
                HeightRequest="50" />

        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Text="Save"
                            Clicked="OnRosterEntrySaveButtonClicked"
                            Grid.Row="1" />
            <Button Text="Delete"
                            Clicked="OnRosterEntryDeleteButtonClicked"
                            Grid.Row="1" 
                            Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is the associated .cs file

```
public partial class RosterEntryPage : ContentPage
    {
        public RosterEntryPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public RosterEntryPage(Player newPlayer)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        async void OnRosterEntrySaveButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var player = (Player)BindingContext;

            player.JoinDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            await App.Database.SavePlayerAsync(player);

            await Navigation.PopAsync();
        }

        async void OnRosterEntryDeleteButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var player = (Player)BindingContext;

            await App.Database.DeletePlayerAsync(player);

            await Navigation.PopAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There's no code on the page that specifies that it has a Player, but
>   I can reference the Player fields in the RosterDetails.xmal file
>   (which is why I call it an "indirect" object)

You can reference the Player fields in the `RosterDetails.xmal` file because you have assigned the `BindingContext` when pushing to `PlayerDetailPage`.

So you can get the current Player by `BindingContext` and pass it to `RosterEntryPage`:

```
public partial class PlayerDetailPage : ContentPage
{
    public PlayerDetailPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    async void OnEditPlayerButtonClicked(object send, EventArgs e)
    {
        await floatingButtonEdit.ScaleTo(1.5, 500);
        await floatingButtonEdit.ScaleTo(0, 500, Easing.SpringOut);

        Player myPlayer = this.BindingContext as Player;

        await Navigation.PushAsync(new RosterEntryPage
        {
            BindingContext = myPlayer
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of setting the page's `BindingContext` before you navigate to it, pass the data via the constructor and let the page set it's own `BindingContext`

```
    Player ViewModel { get; set; }

    public PlayerDetailPage(Player player)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = ViewModel = player;
    }
```

then

```
    async void OnEditPlayerButtonClicked(object send, EventArgs e)
    {
        await floatingButtonEdit.ScaleTo(1.5, 500);
        await floatingButtonEdit.ScaleTo(0, 500, Easing.SpringOut);

        await Navigation.PushAsync(new RosterEntryPage(ViewModel));
    }
```

Comment: Hi Jason,
Thank you for the answer. I added the ViewModel definition to the PlayerDetailPage.xmal.cs and replaced the constructor with the new one. That generated an error on Roster.xmal.cs: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'player' of 'PlayerDetailPage.PlayerDetailPage(Player)'. I modified the call in that file to:
if (e.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                Player selectedPlayer = (e.SelectedItem as Player);

                await Navigation.PushAsync(new PlayerDetailPage (selectedPlayer));
            }
Still empty.

Comment: I'm not sure what "still empty" means.  Are you still getting a compiler error?  Or are you saying the data being passed is null?  Have you used the debugger to step through the code and verify the logic?

Comment: Apologies, I ran out of characters. "Still empty" means that the data field is still not pre-populated on the page like it would be if I called the page directly from selecting a ListView item, and attempting to save from the page crashes the app (which doesn't happen if I call directly from a selected item from ListView). I have tried to use the debugger to step through, but it's of limited use. I can't use the emulator because it doesn't like my processor so I'm running directly on my phone.  The problem may be in how I am calling it in the actual edit page, so I'm adding those above.